# Is this thread-safe ? If not , any suggestions on how to make it one?

Tags: scala, thread-safety

This is a summation function , basically it takes in a functions , and sums it from any `a` to any `b`

Code:

```
object sum {
  def sum(f: Double => Double, lower: Int, upper: Int): Double = {
    @tailrec
    def iter(acc: Double, lower: Int): Double = {
      if (lower > upper) acc
      else iter(acc + f(lower), lower + 1)
    }
    iter(0, lower)
  }
```

How much thread safe is this?
If its not, can someone provide info as to how to make it so ?

Answer (score 3):

As long as `f` is referentially transparent, that is, it has no side effects, it is completely thread safe.

**Edit**:

The real question you should be asking with code like this, or any conditional looping, is "Can the termination condition always be reached?" Can the sequence that is produced from `f(lower) + acc` be guaranteed to satisfy `lower > upper`? For instance, if I were to provide you a monotonically increasing function against an `upper` which is less than `lower` you will never terminate. The loop will be infinite.

Comment: why did you remove the real question part ? But more importantly , can you give an example which shows the side effects part ? I'm new to this..

Comment: @SomjitNag Because I realized that how I phrased it was wrong. The variable `upper` never changes. So the question should be `Can lower > upper ever be reached?` As for an example `sum(_ + 1, 0, -1)` You have a monotonically increasing function for a condition on a variable which is less than the initial condition. I can put it back if you'd like but phrased like that.